# Is there a way to determine whether or not two symbolic boolean expressions are equal in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I've been trying to determine boolean expression equivalence with Sympy, but it seems it doesn't detect equivalence of more complex expressions

```
from sympy.abc import x, y
from sympy.logic.boolalg import *

print(Equivalent(x, x))
print(Equivalent(x, x & True))
print(Equivalent(x | y, y | x))
print(Equivalent(x | (x & y), x | y))
print(Equivalent(~x & ~y, ~(x | y)))
```

Results:

```
>>>True
>>>True
>>>True
>>>Equivalent(Or(x, y), Or(And(x, y), x))
>>>Equivalent(Not(Or(x, y)), And(Not(x), Not(y)))
```

Is there a way to determine whether or not two symbolic boolean expressions are equal in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`equals` works fine for me:

```
( x|(x&y) ).equals( x|y )
# False

( ~x&~y ).equals( ~(x|y) )
# True
```

In general, `equals` tries to transform the two expressions until they are equal to each other and only returns `False` if it fails. It is therefore more accurate (but also slower) than `==`.

Comment: This is the right method. Internally, `equals` uses `satisfiable` on `Equivalent`.

Answer (score 2):

[`sympy.simplify_logic`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.simplify_logic) perhaps?

```
>>> sympy.simplify_logic(Equivalent(Or(x, y), Or(And(x, y), x)))
Or(Not(y), x)
>>> sympy.simplify_logic(Equivalent(Not(Or(x, y)), And(Not(x), Not(y))))
True
```

Comment: This will do more work than necessary in general. You really just want to know if the negation of the `Equivalent` is satisfiable (`satisfiable(Not(Equivalent(a, b)))`), which is what `equals` does.

Comment: @asmeurer then you should post an answer indicating this, looking back on this the first case giving x |~y doesn’t make any sense

Comment: I didn't post an answer because it would have been the same as @Wrzlprmft's answer.

Comment: `simplify_logic` gives `x | ~y` because it is logically equivalent to `(x | y) <=> (x&y | x)` (you can check with a truth table). `simplify_logic` should give you True if the input is a tautology and False if it is a contradiction, but if you don't care beyond that, getting a simplified logically equivalent expression is a lot of extra work (potentially it could be quite slow compared to `equals`, depending on the input expression).

Comment: Oh right - it gives the condition that makes them equal, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

`sympy.Equivalent` doesn't have the boolean satisfiability solver it would need to detect logical equivalence of distinct expressions. In the cases where you got `True`, the objects passed to `Equivalent` were already structurally equal due to transformations performed by `&` and `|`:

```
In [7]: x|y
Out[7]: Or(x, y)

In [8]: y|x
Out[8]: Or(x, y)

In [9]: x&True
Out[9]: x
```

In more complex cases, you'll just get an instance of `Equivalent`.

On the version I'm testing on (0.7.2), I also get True for `Equivalent(~x & ~y, ~(x | y))`, apparently because this version auto-applies De Morgan's laws to `~(x | y)`:

```
In [19]: ~(x|y)
Out[19]: And(Not(x), Not(y))
```

The output for `Equivalent(x | (x & y), x | y)` is definitely right, because that's not actually a tautology. The equivalence doesn't hold when x is false and y is true.